# Unable to find a directory when I know just its name by Find?

Tags: unix, find

I am trying to find the directory called macports by Find.
I do not know where it is in my computer.

I have tried unsuccessfully

```
find --mindepth 777 macports
```

**How can you find the directory?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find . | grep macports
```

From any parent directory you might think it lives in.  Depending on your system you can also try

```
locate macports
```

Answer (score 6):

```
find / -name macports -type d
```

Comment: Use -iname to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @ojblass: what about the symlink called macfind that points to /some/obscure/location/Mac.Find?